# SQL | How to sum in same table but referring to different cell values

Tags: mysql, mariadb, union

As an example, I've a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Sample
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55), `quantity`int(10))
;

INSERT INTO Sample
    (`id`, `productName`, `description`, `quantity`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Cheese', 'GT', 10),
    (1, 'Cheese', 'GE', 10),
    (1, 'Cheese', 'GE', 10),
    (2, 'Ham', 'VD', 10),
    (3, 'Wine', 'EX', 5)
;
```

and I'm trying to get a result so that the calculation is different if the description is of value `GT` and `GE` or `VD`. I tried with `union all`, but it does not seem to work:

```
SELECT x.productName, SUM(x.quantity)
  FROM ( SELECT productName, SUM(quantity*10)
        FROM Sample
        WHERE description IN ('GT', 'GE')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT productName, SUM(quantity*20)
        FROM Sample
        WHERE description IN ('VD')
       ) AS x
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't forget `GROUP BY` clause when using aggregate functions.
- Your inner SUMs aren't aliased, so `x.quantity` won't work.

Try this :

```
SELECT x.productName, SUM(x.quantity) as quantity
FROM 
(
    SELECT productName, SUM(quantity*10) as quantity
    FROM Sample
    WHERE description IN ('GT','GE')
    GROUP BY productName

    UNION ALL
    SELECT productName, SUM(quantity*20) as quantity
    FROM Sample
    WHERE description IN ('VD') 
    GROUP BY productName
) AS x
GROUP BY x.productName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with GT_GE
    as
    (
    select productname, sum(quantity*10) Quantity
    from sample
    where description IN ('GT','GE')
    group by productname
    )
    ,
    VD as
    (
    select productname, sum(quantity*20) Quantity
    from sample
    where description = 'VD'
    group by productname
    )
    select GT_GE.productname, GT_GE.Quantity, VD.productname, VD.quantity 

    from GT_GE, VD
```

Comment: CTEs ("with") are available only in MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 8.0.1.